# Firebase Remote Config Force Refresh on Update on Web (React)

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

**Purpose: I want to achieve the same forced updates on the web as in the app.**

I was thinking of considering Remote Config for Feature Toggle and Maintenance Mode switching, but from reading the documentation, I don't see any way to force a value update.

I have read this article, but it does not describe how to achieve this on the web.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime